# Command-line tool to extract strings using regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

For every completely arbitrary set of three contatenated RE's, "*re1*(*re2*)*re3*", I want a tool (or a one-liner) that will output everything that matches *re2*.  (`\1`)

I am looking for a commonly-available command-line tool that will extract information using an arbitrary regexp, like `grep -o`, but be context-aware, like `expr match`.  The feature I want in `grep -o` is iteration over a file and only printing the match, *except* I don't want to print out the context; the feature I want in `expr match` is the ability to extract from a context (i.e. extract subexpressions). Basically I want to match every subexpression and print it, and only it, out.

*Note:* The following is only a simple example. My question is a general one and could pertain to anything from citing quoted material to extracting XML tags, anything you can write a regex for. ERE is fine, PCRE is better.

For example, say I want to print out everything within a line that's within parentheses, but don't want to print the parentheses. If I do `grep -Eo '([^()]*?)'` I get all the matches, but they have parentheses around them:

Input:

```
$ grep -Eo '\([^()]*?\)' 
foo (bar) baz (bat)
```

Output:

```
(bar)
(bat)
```

*Correct:* Two isolated items. *Incorrect:* They have parens.

Or I could use `expr match`:

```
$ expr match 'foo (bar) baz (bat)' '.*(\([^()]*\)).*'
```

This gives me:

```
bat
```

which correctly has the parens stripped, but misses the first occurrence.

I thought about how to do this in `sed`; one could use substitution, but `sed` eats up the first occurrence like `expr match`:

```
$ echo 'foo (bar) baz (bat)' | sed 's/.*(\([^()]*\)).*/\1/g'
bat
```

Besides, I don't think `sed` is designed to generate two or more lines of output from one line of input (like `grep -o` does); it's more of a line-by-line tool. If `sed` had an option to put the `\`*n* subexpression match into the pattern space or hold space that would work.

I think this might be doable in `gawk` but it doesn't appear straightforward. Like `sed`, `gawk` can do substitution; like `grep`, it can match substrings; like `expr match`, it has trouble with multiple references in a line (though unlike `expr match` there are ways around it).

It can probably be done in Perl, but it would involve a loop of some sort which is getting complicated.

Looking through a lot of related SO questions, a lot of the solutions reply on specific characteristics of a particular problem, but I want a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have gnu grep then you can do it in one step using lookaheads:

```
s='foo (bar) baz (bat)'

grep -Po '(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))' <<< "$s"
bar
bat
```

Or using gnu awk:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\([^()]*\\)' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/[()]/, "", $i); print $i}}' <<< "$s"
bar
bat
```

Or using sed:

```
sed -E 's/[^()]*\(([^()]*)\)/\1:/g' <<< "$s"
bar:bat:
```

Comment: Will these work for arbitrary regexes, though, or are they particular to the example I chose? How would you write them to take, for example, any regex as a parameter?

Comment: Regex needs to modified for different cases as your answer will be modified twice, for `grep` and then `sed`

Comment: It seems to me in most cases `grep` and `sed` can take the same regex just fine, although you do have to be careful I'll concede (as I pointed out, slashes have to be escaped in the `sed` regex, but this won't hurt the `grep` regex so you can use the same syntax for both). What are examples (not counting PCRE or slashes) where `grep` and `sed` cannot take the same regex?

Comment: My point is not about using or not using same regex in grep and sed. It is about doing it in a single step with 3 different ways I shoed in my answer.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood you. I thought you meant the regex needs to be modified twice for my case, but I think you meant that the data has to be modified twice, and you think the superior solution is the one that happens in one step. Am I right?

Answer (score -2):

Inspired by `sendmail`*, I decided that perhaps a two-step process might work where one-step did not.  The solution is simple; use `grep -o` to print out the matches, and `sed` to strip the unwanted context:

```
$ re='\(([^()]*)\)'; echo 'foo (bar) baz (bat)' | grep -Eo "$re" | sed -r "s/$re/\1/1"
bar
bat

$ re="<([^<>]*)>"; echo "I <strong>really</strong> want <A href="http://foo.com">this</A>" | grep -Eo "$re" | sed -r "s/$re/\1/1"
strong
/strong
A href=http://foo.com
/A

$ re="<[^<>]*>([^<]*)<[^<>]*>"; echo "I <strong>really</strong> want <A href="http://foo.com">this</A>" | grep -Eo "$re" | sed -r "s/$re/\1/1"  
really
this

$ re="'([^']*)'"; echo "His name was 'John', her name was 'Jane'" | grep -Eo "$re" | sed -r "s/$re/\1/1"
John
Jane
```

You just have to escape any slashes in the regex or do something to fix the `sed` separator problem.

* `sendmail`, or rather the macros that come with `sendmail`, has this unusual technique (called "focusing") of internally rearranging email addresses and adding extraneous syntax temporarily to make them easier to process.

Comment: If you're going to vote down my answer, especially since I asked the question, please do me the courtesy of explaining how it can be improved and contribute to the discussion and general state of knowledge. Thank you.